# How can I replace some variables in a BDD by CUDD package？

Tags: model-checking, binary-decision-diagram, cudd

Suppose `DdManager` has four variables: `x, y, x', y'` and I have a BDD built by `x` and `y`.
Now I want to change `x` to `x'`, `y` to `y'`, namely, get an identical BDD built by `x'` and `y'`.

How can I get this using the CUDD package? I encountered this problem when I wanted to implement a model checking algorithm. I want to know how to implement this operation or whether I misunderstand the symbolic model checking algorithm?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with the function `Cudd_bddSwapVariables`. It gets the following parameters:

1. A BDD Manager
2. The BDD where you want to replace variables by others.
3. The first array of variables (represented by the BDD nodes that also `Cudd_bddNewVar` would return)
4. The second array of variables
5. The number of variables being swapped.

You will need to allocate and free the arrays yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have read the document and tried this function before but failed. After reading your response, I try again and succeed. Maybe I set wrong parameters before. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Example of variable substitution using the Cython bindings to CUDD that are included in the [package `dd`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd):

```py
from dd import cudd

bdd = cudd.BDD()  # instantiate a shared BDD manager
bdd.declare("x", "y", "x'", "y'")
u = bdd.add_expr(r"x \/ y")  # create the BDD for the disjunction of x and y
rename = dict(x="x'", y="y'")
v = bdd.let(rename, u)  # substitution of x' for x and y' for y
s = bdd.to_expr(v)
print(s)  # outputs:  "ite(x', TRUE, y')"

# another way to confirm that the result is as expected
v_ = bdd.add_expr(r"x' \/ y'")
assert v == v_
```